# Iterator for variable number of nested loops

Tags: python, numpy, iterator

I'm trying to write an iterator for something like this (simplified from original problem):

```
import numpy as np

class IterableNumber:
  def __init__(self, digits):
    self.digits = digits
    self.zero_indices = np.where(digits == 0)[0]
  def __iter__(self):
    return self
  def next(self):
    # For each index in self.zero_indices, loop 1 through 9?
    pass
  # Other methods omitted
```

The IterableNumber takes an array of numbers, but '0' is a wild card.  When I loop through this object, I want each '0' digit to loop through a range of 1 through 9, i.e.

```
num = IterableNumber(np.array([5, 5, 0, 5, 0]))
for digits in num:
  print digits
```

should print

```
[5, 5, 1, 5, 1]
[5, 5, 1, 5, 2]
...
[5, 5, 1, 5, 9]
[5, 5, 2, 5, 1]
[5, 5, 2, 5, 2]
...
...
[5, 5, 9, 5, 9]
```

Writing this iterator for the general case seems to require recursion in order to take care of the variable number of nested loops (one for each 0 present), as other threads on this site would suggest.  But how do I write such a recursive function in the context of the iterator's next() function?  Or maybe there's another way to solve this problem altogether?  Any insight would be appreciated :)

I'm on python 2.7.3 if it's relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product` for this:

```
import numpy as np

from itertools import product

class IterableNumber:
    def __init__(self, digits):
        self.digits = digits
        self.zero_indices = np.where(self.digits==0)[0]
        self.length = len(self.zero_indices)

    def __iter__(self):
        for x in product(range(10), repeat=self.length):
            self.digits[self.zero_indices] = np.array(x)
            yield self.digits
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> for x in IterableNumber(np.array([5, 5, 0, 5, 0])):
    print x
...     
[5 5 0 5 0]
[5 5 0 5 1]
[5 5 0 5 2]
[5 5 0 5 3]
[5 5 0 5 4]
[5 5 0 5 5]
[5 5 0 5 6]
[5 5 0 5 7]
[5 5 0 5 8]
[5 5 0 5 9]
...
...
[5 5 9 5 3]
[5 5 9 5 4]
[5 5 9 5 5]
[5 5 9 5 6]
[5 5 9 5 7]
[5 5 9 5 8]
[5 5 9 5 9]
>>>
```

Comment: Many thanks for the quick response!  This actually will work for everything that I need currently, but I was wondering for my own enrichment (and in case I need to do something like this in the future), does `itertools.product` generalize if I need to iterate some of the indices differently?  A dumb example would be, all even indices I want `range(0, 10, 2)` and all odd indices `range(10)`?

Comment: @xph Sorry I didn't get your example, care to elaborate. ;-)

Comment: Say the input is `[5, 0, 0]` and I want the output to be: 
`[5, 0, 0]`
`[5, 0, 2]`
`...`
`[5, 0, 8]`
`[5, 1, 0]`
`...`
`[5, 2, 0]`
`...`

Comment: @xph I think you will need much more than simple `product` for that.

Comment: I figured about the same.  Well, your solution does what I need it to do, so I'll go ahead and mark it, thanks!